# 404 error for JavaScript source mapped from minified js and source map

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I have a `angular.min.js` JavaScript file and a `angular.min.js.map` source map file for a site. The minified JS file seems to be working fine on the site.

I am using chrome for debugging. Under the "Sources" tab of developer tool, I can see that chrome has loaded up the source map file and created a `angular.js (from source map)`*(in italic)* entry among the scripts. Thus, the source map comment is present in the minified JS file:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=angular.min.js.map
```

However, when I click on this entry on developer tool, the content pane on the right, instead of showing the original source, shows the HTML markup of our 404 page.

I wonder why this is.

As far as I know, developer tool should show the "original" content of the JS source mapped from the minified JS file, which should be dynamically generated by the browser/developer tool, instead of showing the actual content of what is loaded.

Other than angular.min.js, I have a whole bunch of other JS files on the site having similar problems... so I suppose it is not an angular-specific issue.

P.S. The option "Enable JavaScript source maps" is enabled on developer tool.

Comment: No, browser does not generate source. Using source maps browser knows where minified function is starting and ending and in which file

Comment: Sorry, may be "generate isn't the right word here... what I meant is chrome's dev tool should show the "original" source on the right pane.